# Why would someone use two shebangs in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, shebang

I have inherited a medium-sized collection of scripts where some of them start with two shebangs, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
[do stuff]
```

Is there a valid reason for using this construct?

In my experience, any Unix will only respect the first line as a shebang, and the second line will be the first line of the script, which the `sh` interpreter will ignore as being a comment. Should I assume this is a mistake by the programmer? Is there any difference in, say, compatibility or portability if I were to simply remove the second shebang?

Comment: See this: https://superuser.com/q/502984

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right: there is no use for having two shebang lines.  Only the first will ever be used.

Perhaps it was a mistake during some previous automated refactoring.  Just look in your revision control system--I'm absolutely certain whoever did this left a clear and detailed comment explaining their rationale.

Comment: There would be use for two shebang lines:
e.g. if one wants to run the same script sometimes on linux and sometimes on windows, one could state a linux location as shebang and if not found it falls back to windows path.